# Assume the equation $x = At^3 + Bt$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, dimensional-analysis

I would greatly appreciate some help with this. :)

Assume the equation $x = At^3 + Bt$ describes the motion of a particular object, with x having the dimension of length and t having the dimension of time. Determine the dimensions of the constants A and B. (Use the following as necessary: L and T, where L is the unit of length and T is the unit of time.)

[A] =

[B] =

Comment: It would be very helpful to anyone interested in physics pedagogy if you could explain what you found confusing about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given that on the left hand side you have a length, you want a length on the right-hand-side. You can get a length by summing things only if all things are length.
So the problem is asking what measure unit A and B must have for $At$ and $Bt^{3}$ to be length.
But we already know $At$ is a space if A is a velocity, and $[A]=\frac{L}{T}$
Note that $[At]= \frac{L}{T} T$, the T's simplify and we get a length.
For the same reasoning we will want $[B]=\frac{L}{T^{3}}$, so that when we multilply it by a time cubed we get a length.

Answer (score 1):

Solve this problem just like you would solve an algebra problem.  For the equation $x=At^3+Bt$, you need to solve for each constant separately.  Since you know that all terms on both sides of the equation must represent units of length, you can set up the problem like this:

$x=At^3$

Separating $A$, you end up with $A=\frac{x}{t^3}$, which has units of length/time$^3$.

$x=Bt$

Separating $B$ gives $B=\frac{x}{t}$, which has units of length/time.